# Google Analytics & Nivo Slider Clash

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics

I have just added the google analytics code to my webpages and on any pages where there is a Nivo Slider, it has caused the slider to take a very very long time before it loads the images.

When i remove the GA code, everything works fine, does anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried placing the Nivo slider in my `<Head>` and the GA at the very bottom but still no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, when I upload the site to the server the load times are as expected.
Running it locally was when I was getting long load times.